# Clojure Bubble sort function issue

Tags: clojure, bubble-sort

I'm trying to implement bubble sort function in clojure,

Below b_sort function gives error,

But if I execute statements inside b_sort function it works,

```
(def r_list (take 10 (repeatedly #(rand-int 100))))
(def r_vec (vec r_list))
(def cnt (count r_vec))
(defn b_sort
    (loop [i 0]
      (if (< i cnt)
        (loop [j (+ i 1)]
          (if (< j cnt)
            (do
              (def a (r_vec i))
              (def b (r_vec j))
              (if (> a b)
                (do 
                  (def r_vec (assoc r_vec i b j a))
                  (println r_vec)
                )
              )
              (if (< j cnt)
                (recur (inc j)
              )))
            )        
          )
        )
        (if (< i cnt)
          (recur (inc i)
        )
      )
    )
)
```

Below is the error in b_sort function,

> ```
> (if (< i cnt) (recur (inc i)))))
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> should satisfy
>
>   vector?
>
> or value
>
>   (... (loop ... ... ...))
>         ^^^^
>
> should satisfy
>
>   vector?
> ```

Comment: A couple of unrelated comments: don't use `def` for local bindings, use `let` instead, and don't move closing parentheses to a new line, more details here: https://guide.clojure.style/#gather-trailing-parens. Also `if`s with only a "then" branch can and often should be replaced with `when`.

Comment: Here's a gist with a more idiomatic version of what you wrote - I left some bugs in there as an exercise (since this is homework after all) - https://gist.github.com/harold/3f8ebe1244067e45e57b009571739c88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was no arguments in the `defn` statement,

When I changed the statement to `(defn b_sort []` it worked.